# Stop pyyaml from putting key values into list, instead put into a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, yaml, format

Here is a yaml file I have:

```
animal:
    - dog:
        - noise:
            - "woof"
        - food:
            - "dog food"
        - house:
            - "dog house"
    - cat:
        - noise:
            - "meow"
        - food:
            - "cat food"
        - home:
            - "cat tree"
```

Here is the code I use to convert yaml to dictionary:

```
import yaml, pprint
from pathlib import Path

def gen_vars(conf_file)
    conf = yaml.safe_load(Path(config_file).read_text())
    pprint.pprint(conf)
    return

gen_vars('./conf.yaml')
```

But here is the output:

```
{'animal': [{'dog': [{'noise': ['woof']},
                     {'food': ['dog food']},
                     {'house': ['dog house']}]},
            {'cat': [{'noise': ['meow']},
                     {'food': ['cat food']},
                     {'home': ['cat tree']}]}]
}
```

Problems I have with this output:

- Every value is in a list. I dont want that.
- Every key/value pair is in a dictionary. I dont want that.
- Every key and value are in single quotes. I dont want that.
  I want this instead:

```
{"animal": {"dog": {"noise": "woof",
                     "food": "dog food",
                     "house": "dog house"}},
            {"cat": {"noise": "meow",
                     "food": "cat food",
                     "home": "cat tree"}}
}
```

Am I formatting my yaml incorrectly? How can I get this type of output?

**EDIT:**

I figured out how to remove nested lists with dictionaries for each key value pair. This post answered my question:
[Load yaml list as dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47314588/load-yaml-list-as-dictionary)

Need to format without the `-`

```
animal:
    dog:
        noise:
            "woof"
        food:
            "dog food"
        house:
            "dog house"
    cat:
        noise:
            "meow"
        food:
            "cat food"
        home:
            "cat tree"
```

Output:

```
{'animal': {'cat': {'food': 'cat food', 'home': 'cat tree', 'noise': 'meow'},
            'dog': {'food': 'dog food', 'house': 'dog house', 'noise': 'woof'}}
```

Still, is there a way to make all single quotes double without converting to a string and using `replace("\'","\"")`?

Comment: Please don't shift gears with an edit. Close or delete the question and ask a new one. In the mean time, the quotes aren't part of the value. If you `print(mydict['animal']['cat']['food'])` you will get `cat food`. If you want `"cat food"` instead then do something like: `print(f'''"{mydict['animal']['cat']['food']}"''')`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and comment. First of all I did not shift gears. Converting `'` to `"` was apart of my original question. I stated "Every key and value are in single quotes. ...". Second, I am looking to make all of the dictionary (keys and values) surrounded by double quotes. Not just the end value. Is that possible to do or tell pyyaml to do as output?

Comment: "NM for most of this." <- shifting gears. The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38369833/26428) might provide some help for preserving quotes.